# Docker doesn't kill containers on OOM

Tags: linux, docker, out-of-memory

I made two containers, both `malloc` in a loop until the server runs out of memory on a remote server running Debian 9 with enabled swap (4 GB RAM 1 GB swap). When running a single one (the host doesn't have any other services running, pretty much only dockerd), it gets killed in a minute or so, and everything is fine. Running 2/3 at the same time cause the server to lock out, making SSH unresponsive. Why don't these containers (I suppose they have really high OOM scores) get killed by OOM?

Comment: Are you using docker on Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Do you have swap enabled?